# what happens if we do not load the module initially using sap.ui.define but try to access it in code?

Tags: sapui5

Would like to explain it with example.
Suppose we have a controller and we try to create a model using -
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({});

But we have no where loaded  sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel before writing this code.

Will it work? If yes, then why does it throw error in some other scenarios.

May be I am little confused regarding library and module loading in ui5 application, so could anyone help with it?

Comment: Could you give a code example, please?

Answer (score 1):

Referencing UI5 modules with their *fully qualified module name* (e.g. `new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel()`) is **not** recommended at all!

Is there any reason why you don't add `"sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"` to the controller's dependency?

If you really need to access a module at runtime, at least encapsulate it in `sap.ui.require`

```js
//...
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function(JSONModel) {
  const oModel = new JSONModel({});
  // ...
});
```

- [API reference: `sap.ui.require`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui#methods/sap.ui.require)
- It's also possible to [require modules in XML view and fragment](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/b11d853a8e784db6b2d210ef57b0f7d7).